# display [no image found] when image src returns no image

Tags: html, asp.net, image, src

I generate my image `src` from databse field called [pictureName]. I want when Picture name is null or the name doesn't return image to display [image not found] picture.

Here is my aspx code to generate img:

```
<img src="WEBIMAGES/<%#Eval("BrandName")%>/<%# Eval("PictureName") %>" alt="" title="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>">
```

my images divided into folders for each brand. i have `noImage.jpg` in every folder.

how to display this image when no image displayed.

I'm using asp.net webforms

I tried to use `onerror` event, but not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a coalesce on the picture name as follows:

```
<img src="WEBIMAGES/<%#Eval("BrandName")%>/<%# Eval("PictureName") ?? 'noImage.jpg' %>" alt="" title="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>">
```

Comment: dam you beet me to it :P

Comment: @SamDenton I get beaten to it all the time too. :)

Comment: If only I could type faster :(

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code like this

```
<img src="WEBIMAGES/<%#Eval("BrandName")%>/<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PictureName").ToString()) ? "noImage.jpg" : Eval("PictureName") %>" alt="" title="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>">
```

Comment: Great. If mine is correct, please accept as a correct answer.